# Java - Extracting plaintext from web-page source code (getting massive quantities of lyrics from website)

Tags: java, web-scraping, pseudocode

O community, I'm in the process of writing the pseudocode for an application that extracts song lyrics from a remote host (web-server, not my own) by reading the page's source code. 
This is assuming that:

- Lyrics are being displayed in plaintext
- Portion of source code containing lyrics is readable by Java front-end application

I'm not looking for source code to answer the question, but what is the technical term used for querying a remote webpage for plaintext content?

If I can determine the webpage naming scheme, I could set the pointer of the URL object to the appropriate webpage, right? The only limitations would be irregular capitalization, and would only be effective if the plaintext was found in EXACTLY the same place.

Do you have any suggestions?
I was thinking something like this for "Buck 65", singing "I look good"

> - URL url = new URL(http://www.elyrics.net/read/b/buck-65-lyrics/i-look-good-lyrics.html);
>
>   - I could substitute "buck-65-lyrics" & "i-look-good-lyrics" to reflect user input?
>   - Input re-directed to PostgreSQL table
>
> Current objective:
>
> - User will request name of {song, artist, album}, Java front-end will query remote webpage
> - Full source code (containing plaintext) will be extracted with Java front-end
> - Lyrics will be extracted from source code (somehow)
> - If song is not currently indexed by PostgreSQL server, will be added to table.
> - Operations will be made on the plaintext to suit the objectives of the program

I'm only looking for direction. If I'm headed completely in the wrong direction, please let me know. This is only for the pseudocode. I'm not looking for answers, or hand-outs, I need assistance in determining what I need to do. Are there external libraries for extracting plaintext that you know of? What technical names are there for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks, Tyler

Comment: You need an html parser. Then you can use things like classes and ids to extract your content.

Comment: How will the website owner react to having their entire content slurped by a 'bot?  What about having their bandwidth saturated while you do it?  How will the copyright owners feel about their intellectual property being served by an unauthorized site?  How big is your legal defense fund?

Comment: I know you didn't ask, but what the heck. http://ideone.com/Zfwm0

Comment: @JimGarrison: this project is being used for purely academic purposes, and will only consist of a few queries. I realize that by doing so, I'm a nefarious individual, but I need to get my degree in applied computer science somehow.

Comment: This is not [tag:data-mining] (a special type of *statistical* analysis), but the technical term is [tag:web-scraping]

Comment: P.S. mass-scraping lyrics from web pages is almost certainly a violation of the terms of use of that site. Publishing them on your own web page without a license of all the lyrics *authors* is a copyright violation and can quickly get you a DMCA complaint, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is referred to as [screen or data scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).  Note that employing it often breaks the target service's [terms of service](http://www.elyrics.net/tos.html).  Usually, this is not a robust approach, which is why API-like services with guarantees about how they operate are preferable.

Your approach sounds like it will work for the most part, but a few things to keep in mind.

- If the web service you're interacting with requires a very precise URL scheme, you should not feed your user-provided data directly into it, since it is likely to be muddied by missing words, abbreviations, or misspellings.  You might be better off doing some sort of search, first, and using that search's best result.
- Reading HTML data is more complicated than you think.  Use an existing library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to assist you.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I can't tell if you are joking; didn't I do that in the second sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The technical term to extract content from a site is web scraping, you can google that. There are a lot of online libraries, for java there is jsoup. Though its easy to write your own regex.
1st thing I would do i use curl and get the content from the site just for testing, this will give you a fair idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a HTML parser. One of the most popular is [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Take care abut the legal aspect fo what you you do ;)